# MCMC changing multiple parameters

Tags: monte-carlo, markov-process

What is the standard way of drawing multiple parameters for a MCMC run? Say I have 9 parameters, what is the most efficient method to get all parameters to explore their distributions properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should explore their [joint] distribution [no s] rather than [marginal] distributions. Second, it all depends on the structure of the target, i.e., whether or not, the parameters come as groups that can be simulated at once as a single vector. In case one is unsure, one parameter at a time Gibbs sampling is the default method [I](http://amzn.to/2kSOnNa) would recommend.